# Insert records by user who's connected Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have  a form  (F1) where user will provide their respective credentials username and password .

After a sucessfull login , the controls moves to the Client Form (F2) and display welcome username in a label on it.

**Client Form contains:**

1. labels and textboxes(name, address, function , ...)
2. Button Insert
3. DataGridView bind to DB (name, address, function ,.., ***UserId)***

Now , I want to insert a Client.

After filling textboxes, I want to add a Client a show it added by user who's connected.

**Ex:** if I logged with Username Rose after that add a client, in my datagridView , show me my row of insert added by Rose.

**Code of my Login and passing username to Client Form**

```
  private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //textBox2.Text = Encrypt(textBox2.Text);
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=User-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=timar;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select Username from [User] where Username='" + textBox1.Text + "' and Password='" + textBox2.Text + "'", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                this.Hide();
                Client c = new Client(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
                v.Show();
            }
            else if (dt.Rows.Count > 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Nom d'utilisateur et Mot de passe dupliqué !");
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Nom d'utilisateur ou Mot de passe incorrecte !");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

**Here is my code of Insert:**

```
 public Client(string username)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

       lblUser.Text = username;

        DisplayData();
        FillData();

    }
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
  {  
      if (  comboBox2.SelectedValue != null && textBox1.Text != string.Empty && textBox2.Text != string.Empty && textBox4.Text != string.Empty)  
      {  
          string cmdStr = "Insert into Client  (idUser,name,address,function,telephone,commentaire)values (@idUser,@name,@,address,@function,@telephone,@commentaire)";  
          SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=User-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=timar;Integrated Security=True");  
          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, con);  
          con.Open();  

         //The problem in the line below how Can I get the id of username,Error cannot convert string Rose to int.  
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idUser",label.Text);  
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", (comboBox2.SelectedValue));  
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@,address", textBox1.Text);  
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@function", textBox2.Text);  
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telephone", textBox4.Text);  
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@commentaire",txtArchive.Text);  


          int LA = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
          con.Close();  
          MessageBox.Show("Le Client a été ajouter avec succés !","Saisie Rendez-vous", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);  
          DisplayData();  
          ClearData();  
      }  
      else  
      {  
          MessageBox.Show("Vérifier que tous les champs sont remplis !","Erreur",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);  
      }  
  }
```

I am not able to figure out how to do this, I am very new to c# and trying to learn.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your question is unclear, what part exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: I explain my issue in a comment in my code above , I want to add a new Client and want to know that was added by Whom(User who's connected = Rose)?

Comment: ooooh the actual question is in a code comment - yeah thats not the best place for it!

Comment: You can remember the login user and pass it to form2, is that what you want ?

Comment: Do you have a user table which has the `Id` for each user's `Username`?

Comment: Yes of course, I have

Comment: So why cant you just look up your user Id from the username before inserting in to Client?

Comment: When checking for login, write your query this way: `SELECT [Id], [UserName] from [Users] WHERE [UserName] = @UserName AND Password = @Password` and store the [Id] and [UserName] which you get from the query if the resultset contains one record. Then every time you need the `Id` of logged-in user, use it.

Comment: @RezaAghaei , If I do **select Id From [Users]**, Then I can't retrieve mY `Username` in Client FoRM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When checking for login, write your query this way:

```
SELECT [Id], [UserName] from [Users] WHERE [UserName]=@UserName AND [Password]=@Password
```

Then store both `[Id]` and `[UserName]` which you get from the query when the login is successful (the resultset contains one record). This way you can use username and id of the logged-in user every time you need.

For example:

```
var cmd = @"SELECT [Id], [UserName] FROM [Users] " +
          @"WHERE [UserName] = @UserName AND [Password] = @Password";
var cn = @"Data Source=User-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=timar;Integrated Security=True";
var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, cn);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", textBox1.Text);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", textBox2.Text);
var dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
{
    int id = dt.Rows[0].Field<int>("Id");
    string userName = dt.Rows[0].Field<string>("UserName");
    //...
}
```

**Note:**

- You should used parametrized query to prevent SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: The first record of result `DataTable` contains both `Id` and `UserName`. dt.Rows[0]. For example `int id = dt.Rows[0].Field<int>("Id");` and `string userName = dt.Rows[0].Field<int>("UserName");`

Comment: If I run my program and try to log in , It show me an Error : the object reference is not defined

Comment: It seems you know how to run a parametrized command, so I didn't add it to the answer. Surely you can solve object null reference exception yourself. I don't have any code in the answer. Do you need more help?

Comment: I added an example of how you can use parametrized queries with data adapter.

Comment: Do you need any other help applying the solution?

Comment: I have the same problem too ,When I debug this line `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idUser",_userId);` The value of _userId is 0 and I don't have the value 0 in my table, this why show me an error **INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint**

Comment: The thing you should verify is this line: `int id = dt.Rows[0].Field<int>("Id");`. After than line what's the value of `id`?

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, parameterize your queries for login! At the moment you are VERY susceptible to SQL Injection attack! Lest you get a visit from [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).

---

In answer to your question, change the query on your login form to return both the user's Id and their username.

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select Id, Username from [User] where Username=@Username and Password=@Password", con);
```

Now, when you read the single result you can get Id from field `0` and username from field `1`.

```
if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
{
    this.Hide();
    var row = dt.Rows[0];
    int userId = (int)row[0];
    string username = (string)row[1];
    Client c = new Client(userId, username);
    v.Show();
}
```

Note also in that code, I'm passing both to the `Client` form. Update the constructor to save both pieces of information in local variables:

```
public class Client : Form
{
    private int _userId;

    public Client(int userId, string username)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _userId = userId;
        lblUser.Text = username;

        DisplayData();
        FillData();
    }
}
```

Thereafter, you can use `_userId` anywhere you like in `Client` form. E.g. in the save button click:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idUser",_userId);
```